# How do you compile the occi demo on ubuntu?

Tags: oracle, occi

It's 2021, does Oracle not support modern operating systems that use compiler ABIs released over 6 years ago?

```
$ make -f demo.mk
rm -rf SunWS_cache
rm -rf cdemo81 cdemo81.o occidml occidml.o occiobj occiobj.o occiobjo* occiobjm* occiobj.h occiobjout.type
/usr/bin/gcc -c -I../include -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -g cdemo81.c
/usr/bin/g++ -o cdemo81 -g cdemo81.o -L../../ -locci -lclntsh -lpthread
make -f demo.mk buildocci OBJS=occidml.o EXE=occidml
rm -rf SunWS_cache
/usr/bin/g++ -c -I../include -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -g occidml.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -o occidml -g occidml.o -L../../ -locci -lclntsh -lpthread
occidml.cpp:291: error: undefined reference to 'oracle::occi::SQLException::getMessage[abi:cxx11]() const'
occidml.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'oracle::occi::SQLException::getMessage[abi:cxx11]() const'
occidml.cpp:83: error: undefined reference to 'oracle::occi::SQLException::getMessage[abi:cxx11]() const'
occidml.cpp:106: error: undefined reference to 'oracle::occi::SQLException::getMessage[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Oracle (client or server) does not support Ubuntu at all. It is designed for the Red Hat branch of Linux. The only supported Linux variants are Red Hat, Oracle Linux, and SuSE.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/compilers-and-development-tools_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8 states that RHEL8 upgraded to the new ABI for libstdc++.

Comment: Yes, but your question was about Ubuntu specifically, which is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The default libocci.so.19.1 is not compatible with g++ versions 5 and above. Please contact Oracle support to get the specially built libocci to work with g++ 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated libocci_gcc53.so.21.1 lib for that.

It actually works with any GCC version above 5. Oracle just chose that weird name "53" because GCC 5 is the first version where the new libstdc++ "cxx11" ABI for std::string and std::list appeared.

It's not included yet in the *Instant* Client. You need to download the full "client "home" or whatever Oracle likes to call this thing.

See "Database Client Installation Guide for Linux" -> "Installation Requirements for Programming Environments for Linux x86-64" https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/installation-requirements-for-programming-environments-for-linux-x86-64.html#GUID-BFD716A4-6235-49F6-8259-A534E2D96A8D

Answer (score -1):

For the supported Linux platforms, please try
make -f demo_rdbms.mk occidemos (for building all OCCI demos)
make -f demo_rdbms.mk occidml (for building just one demo like occidml)
make -f demo_rdbms.mk buildocci EXE=myapp OBJS=myapp.o (for a custom .cpp program)
The above is with a regular installation. You didn't mention which version of OCCI you are trying and the version of g++.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the `cdemo81.c` is a clue.